# How to correctly identify anomalies using Isolation Forest and resulting scores?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to detect outliers in a dataframe using the Isolation Forest algorithm from sklearn.

Here's the code I'm using to set up the algorithm:

```
iForest = IsolationForest(n_estimators=100, max_samples=256, contamination='auto', random_state=1, behaviour='new')
iForest.fit(dataset)
scores = iForest.decision_function(dataset)
```

Now, since I don't know what a good value for the contamination could be, I would like to check my scores and decide where to draw the line based on the distribution of the scores. Here's the code for the graph and the graph itself:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.hist(scores, bins=50);
```

[image]

Is it correct to assume that negative scores indicate outliers in my dataframe? I can't find a good explanation on the range of the IF scores and how these scores work (why do I get negative scores?).

Additionally, is there a way to attach these scores to the original dataset and manually check rows with negative scores to see if they make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have information about the anomalies in your present dataset?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't

Answer (score 4):

One way of approaching this problem is to make use of the [score_samples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.score_samples) method that is available in sklearn's `isolationforest` module. Once you have fitted the model to your data, use the `score_samples` method to find out the abnormality scores for each sample (lower the value more abnormal it is). Since you don't have the information about true anomalies in your data, you can sort your samples w.r.t the scores that you have obtained and manually review the records to see if the sample with the least score is actually an anomaly or not and in this process you can come up with a threshold value for classifying a data point as an anomaly, which you can use it later on for any new data to check if they are anomalies or not.

Comment: what's the difference between the scores from the decision_function method and the score_samples method? I've read the documentation but I can't understand it

Comment: I guess you could either of them for your case.

Answer (score 2):

the return value of `score_samples` is  $-s(x,\psi)$ , which range is $[-1,0]$, 0 means decision length is short so abnomal.

`decision_function` will convert `score_samples` to $[-0.5,0.5]$
then `predict` will convert `decision_function` to $-1$ or $1$ by predefined anomaly rate(`contamination`)

```py
iforest = IsolationForest(n_estimators=100,
                          max_features=1.0,
                          max_samples='auto',
                          contamination='auto',
                          bootstrap=False,
                          n_jobs=1,
                          random_state=1)

iforest.fit(X)

scores = iforest.score_samples(X)
predict = iforest.predict(X)
decision = iforest.decision_function(X)
offset = iforest.offset_ # default -0.5

print(offset)
print(iforest.max_samples_)
assert np.allclose(decision, scores-offset)
assert np.allclose(predict, np.where(decision<0,-1,1))
```